# End IF not in range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a game with MS Excel and I need this actions to stop if it's out of my range, which is my table of game called "table16x16". Program is if you run the game and click on hidden blank cell then program looks in all 8 ways to find non blank cell (till finds) and then shows them all (I hope it's clear). Aniway, when I click one that has no filled cells around it's goes out of table to search for any and fills cells out of table with colors till the end of sheet (goes up and left till the end). I would like it to end in my "table16x16" and stop looking outside. May anyone help me and show me how can I do this?

My code:

```
Sub ClearTheCells(myCell As Range)
    myCell.Font.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
    myCell.Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
    myCell.Value = "."

    If myCell.Offset(-1, -1) = "" Then
        ClearTheCells myCell.Offset(-1, -1)
    End If

    If myCell.Offset(0, -1) = "" Then
        ClearTheCells myCell.Offset(0, -1)
    End If

    If myCell.Offset(1, -1) = "" Then
        ClearTheCells myCell.Offset(1, -1)
    End If

    If myCell.Offset(-1, -0) = "" Then
        ClearTheCells myCell.Offset(-1, 0)
    End If

    If myCell.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then
        ClearTheCells myCell.Offset(1, 0)
    End If

    If myCell.Offset(-1, 1) = "" Then
        ClearTheCells myCell.Offset(-1, 1)
    End If

    If myCell.Offset(1, 1) = "" Then
        ClearTheCells myCell.Offset(1, 1)
    End If

    If myCell.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then
        ClearTheCells myCell.Offset(0, 1)
    End If

    If IsNumeric(myCell.Offset(-1, -1)) Then
        myCell.Offset(-1, -1).Font.Color = vbBlack
        myCell.Offset(-1, -1).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
    End If

    If IsNumeric(myCell.Offset(0, -1)) Then
        myCell.Offset(0, -1).Font.Color = vbBlack
        myCell.Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
    End If

    If IsNumeric(myCell.Offset(1, -1)) Then
        myCell.Offset(1, -1).Font.Color = vbBlack
        myCell.Offset(1, -1).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
    End If

    If IsNumeric(myCell.Offset(-1, 0)) Then
        myCell.Offset(-1, 0).Font.Color = vbBlack
        myCell.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
    End If

    If IsNumeric(myCell.Offset(-1, 1)) Then
        myCell.Offset(-1, 1).Font.Color = vbBlack
        myCell.Offset(-1, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
    End If

    If IsNumeric(myCell.Offset(1, 1)) Then
        myCell.Offset(1, 1).Font.Color = vbBlack
        myCell.Offset(1, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
    End If

    If IsNumeric(myCell.Offset(0, 1)) Then
        myCell.Offset(0, 1).Font.Color = vbBlack
        myCell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
    End If

    If IsNumeric(myCell.Offset(1, 0)) Then
        myCell.Offset(1, 0).Font.Color = vbBlack
        myCell.Offset(1, 0).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your game, but I think the Intersect method can help resolve the problem. I'm just showing an example of how it works below. Try to modify it to meet your requirements.

In the example below, I set `myCell = 11`. Next, I checked if `myCell` is within a range that I defined as cells A1:C10. If not, it gives an error message. Else, it gives a success message

```
Dim myCell As Range

Set myCell = Range("A11")

If Intersect(myCell, Range("A1:C10")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("YOU CLICKED OUTSIDE THE TABLE")
Else
    MsgBox ("ALL GOOD")
End If
```

Comment: it's actually a game called Minesweeper that I'm working on. I have code to generate numbers and all other stuff. But struggle with this thing.

Comment: Did the code I posted help you at all? If not, how are you defining which range is in table 16x16?

Comment: it's not exactly what I need I think. My "table16x16" is just 16x16 table selected and named that way. I need code to search for integers around and if none found in range of table just mark these cells with a color + integers found (after searching all 8 ways)

Comment: I think I understand better. The problem is that you've got a recursive subroutine with no break designation. You will have to check each *IF* statement to see if it's in your range. I will show one example: `IF NOT Intersect(myCell.Offset(-1, -1), "table16x16") is nothing then ClearTheCells(myCell.Offset(-1,-1)`

Comment: does not work anyway - it's actually clears in range, but clears full cells as well till left top and at the end I get error message

Comment: aniway, I found more efficient way to do it without any codes. I placed any integers or symbols all around the table and make them invisible (Format Cells->Custom->;;;). Now it works perfectly fine.